# LaTeX keeps putting my figure alone in last page

Tags: floats, subfloats

everyone.

I'm writing my thesis and I'm having some trouble with `\subfigure` package. I have this code below in some part of my text:

```
Some big text with a few explanations here...
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfigure[Fig4.5a]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Fig.4.5a}
\label{Figure 4.5a}}
\quad
\subfigure[Fig4.5b]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Fig4.5b}
\label{Figure 4.5b}}
\subfigure[Fig.45c]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{Fig4.5c}
\label{Figure 4.5c}}
\caption{Caption from Figure 4.5}
\label{Figure 4.5}
\end{figure}
```

This code above is repeated 3 times (because I have a set of 12 charts to place and I have to explain each other) and it fills 4 entire pages (and that's ok, I don't need small charts, I need big ones so it is good to read). Then comes a text with some explanations, I begin another section with a short text and then I include another 2 charts, like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!t]
\centering
\subfigure[Fig4.9a]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{Fig4.9a}
\label{Figure 4.9a}}
\quad
\subfigure[Fig4.9b]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{Fig4.9b}
\label{Figure 4.9b}}
\caption{Caption from Figure 4.9}
\label{Figure 4.9}
\end{figure}
```

The problem begins in this last picture. All the text I type ***after*** this last figure (Figure 4.9) comes ***before*** this figure and my Figure 4.9 is placed in a single page, alone.

My question: is there a way not to let the Figure 4.9 alone in a single page? I know LaTeX will float my figures and fit it the best way, but I have to pass 5 pages so I can see a chart that was mentioned 5 pages before. As I see it, there is a way for LaTeX to rearrange the space and put some text after Figure 4.9. I tried `\pagebreak`, but didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `[!h]` means not top  (t) not bottom (b) and not on a float page (p) so makes it virtually impossible to place the float anywhere, `[!ht]` is slightly better but you should always include `p`

Answer (score 7):

You have explicitly prevented latex from putting the float on a page on its own, as you have used the optional argument and not included `p` so over-riding the default `[tbp]`. So not using the option or including `p` would probably help.

`\pagebreak` does not flush pending floats you need `\clearpage` for that, although that may not be needed if the floats are allowed to be positioned automatically on float pages.

It's hard to give specific advice as you have not provided any usable example code.

Comment: Thank you very much, David! It's a little better now that I removed the argument [ht] that I insisted on writing in the /subfigure code.